# Is there a way to pass in variable element ID from Highcharts to launch a modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to pass in variable elementIDs from HighCharts label elements into a javascript function, using these I would like to launch the required divs in a jquery modal window.

I have my example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4LLM/27/

```
function ShowTable(TableID)
{
var ID = TableID;
$("#TableID").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: false,
        minWidth: 700,
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: window
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {},
    });

$("#TableID").dialog("open");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Graph').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Test Title'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function(event) {
                        var options = this.options;
                        var str = options.name.split(" ");
                        ShowTable('DataToShow' + str[1]);
                    }
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>:' + this.point.y;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Calls Assigned',
        data: [
            ['Item 1', 0],
            ['Item 2', 0],
            ['Item 3', 1],
            ['Item 4', 0],
            ['Item 5+', 0], ]
    }]
});
});
```

The issue I have is, TableID does not seem to work in the ShowTable Function - the variable get defined correctly, and the modal windows works if you manually add the correct div ID, but does not work when the div id is passed in via the HighCharts OnClick event

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ID = TableID;  <-- variable
$("#TableID").dialog({  <--string
```

Don't you want to use the value you passed in and not the hard coded string?

```
$("#" + TableID).dialog({
```

and

```
$("#" + TableID).dialog("open");
```

Comment: Yep, ... been a long day just didn't see that - Thanks for the help!